# HP Designjet 5000ps not printing

Tags: usb, drivers

I have an old HP Designjet 5000 ps that I have managed to install drivers for using a Dell Latitude D820 running Windows XP Pro. I installed both drivers, the postscript driver and the GL2 driver.

When I send a document to print (using Adobe Reader) the plotter says it's receiving the file and continues to say the same until the message disappears but nothing is really plotted. I am connected via a generic USB cable that I purchased brand new but am a little doubtful of it. Can it be that I installed the drivers incorrectly or can it be that the USB cable is faulty?

It does at times give me errors saying the print failed to send and the cable I am using is a Parallel to USB cable. I do not get any errors reported by the plotter when I turn it on.

I tried to print a test page from the XP machine and it said that it finished uploading it on the print queue. The printer just said "Ready" but the dialogue menu was unresponsive, likely crashed.

Whenever I try to upload a job it gets stuck at 64KB.

How can I resolve these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By buying a new usb-serial cable that comes with a disk and installing those drivers, this problem was surpassed.

Getting this error now:
[HP Designjet 5000ps timeout error](https://superuser.com/questions/737930/hp-designjet-5000ps-timeout-error)