# HP Designjet 5000ps timeout error

Tags: windows-xp, printer

Here is my previous question, which was resolved. 
[HP Designjet 5000ps not printing](https://superuser.com/questions/732579/hp-designjet-5000ps-not-recieving-print)

Currently my issue is that after the file is uploaded, the printer goes into a faze where it says its testing the printheads, and then spits out the following error:

[image]

Error Timeout
Offending command: timeout

STACK:

(list of commands I assume).

What is the issue? Is there a way to fix this?

I am using an xp sp3 computer with this printer.

Could the problem be the cable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I got this printer to work finally after several weeks of frustration so the process i took is as follows

I bought a parallel to USB cable from staples and installed the driver it came with 
i then proceeded to uninstall the printer which as i mentioned before i had installed before but would not print
After this i proceed to restart the computer and once booted i turned on the plotter and was immediately prompted that my HP DesignJet5000ps had been found. I then clicked on the option to manually install the drivers as i did not have the original cd so i downloaded them from here

http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdHome/?javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.prp_bd9b6997fbc7fc515f4cf4626f5c8d01=wsrp-navigationalState%3DswEnvOID%253D228%257CswLang%253D%257Caction%253DlistDriver&javax.portlet.tpst=bd9b6997fbc7fc515f4cf4626f5c8d01&sp4ts.oid=20992&ac.admitted=1396668226707.876444892.492883150#Driver

I downloaded both the postscript and the raster drivers from here

i then selected the location of the postscript driver wich has the following name "dj5000" it then ask to insert the cd or floppy for the hpltdrv2 which is the raster driver so you simply click next and it will bring up a window to browse for it since you don't have the CD driver after that you will choose the location to were you downloaded the file which should be named hpltdrv2.dll it will be the only file it finds as it is looking specifically for that name and extension as long as you pint it to you download folder

ohh and well to clarify i downloaded both drivers and extracted the "HP Designjet HPGL/2 and Raster driver for Windows AutoCAD 2000- AutoCAD 2005" to the root of my downloads folder and extracted the "HP Designjet 5000ps Adobe PS3 PostScript Driver" onto another folder within the downloads folder just to make it easier for me to identify which one was which hope this helps